# Google People API: search_person_directory_people doesn't return any data

Tags: ruby, google-people-api

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople), `search_person_directory_people` should return a "list of domain profiles and domain contacts in the authenticated user's domain directory that match the search query", but it consistently returns nothing except for my own email address.

I'm doing something like this (ruby):

```
service = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleServiceService.new
# authentication code
service.search_person_directory_people(query: 'john@example.com', read_mask: 'emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers', sources: 'DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE')
=> #<Google::Apis::PeopleV1::SearchDirectoryPeopleResponse:0x0000xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

I'm using ruby 2.4, and google gem 0.52.0.

Anyone else has seen this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. This method is returning the contacts that match the specific query. Is `john@example.com` one of your contacts?

Comment: No, `john@example.com` is just an example. I tried with most of the contacts in my Google Contacts directory, and I only get a result when I query my own email address.

Comment: As I said, I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you are authenticating with the right account, and that you have the contacts you think you have?